# Trouble manually entering date with AirBnB's DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-dates

I'm working on a bug in my company's code that uses AirBnB React Date's package, specifically the `DateRangePicker` component. If the user tries entering a date without two digits (such as `9/1/19` instead of `09/01/2019`), MomentJS doesn't seem to pick it up as a valid format. I know Moment has format strings, but I can't seem to think of how I could hook into this component to modify it.

I tried the `onDatesChange` method provided, but it provides two Moment objects, and so when the format isn't just right, it just returns nulls. Ideally, I'd like to make it so if the user enters a date or uses the calendar selector, it validates. I'm happy to do formatting myself (convert `9/1/19` to `09/01/2019`), but I can't figure out where I can do that.

Comment: Can you supply a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `displayFormat` prop of `DateRangePicker`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mayer-ygwlr